# schema.graphql vs. buildSchema()

Tags: graphql, relayjs, react-relay

Following the *Relay Modern* documentation, first I started off by using the `buildSchema()` function and placing my *schema* and *rootValue* in JavaScript file and use it whenever needed.

Later I found out that `relay-compiler` needs a schema file either in JSON or `.graphql` format; So I copied my schema in `schema.graphql` and everything works as expected.

To avoid maintaining my schema in two places I can read the `schema.graphql` file and pass it to the `buildSchema()` function and it should work, but I was wondering if that's the correct approach or if there are better ways of doing it? Is there any way to avoid using `buildSchema()` function at all and totally rely on `schema.graphql` solely?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct and required approach.
You can't avoid using the `buildSchema` function with your `.graphql` file ; but you could construct the full schema in JavaScript - [see bottom of this page](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/).

I recommend sticking with the Schema Language notation though.

Comment: Just for the clarification, are you saying that reading from schema.graphql and passing it to the buildSchema function is the correct approach, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly ;)